# ContentService.createTextOutput removes array but array needed array can be like "[]" or [] in Google Apps Script

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Google Apps Script removes array My function is

```
function getAllProducts() {
  const spreadsheetId = '000000-PA2yI4OmUjTn3xz9o4faP-8-iPOniBYc0kuKc';
  const rangeName = 'Products!A2:I1000';
  try {
    const values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, rangeName).values;
    if (!values) {
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("No Product Found");
    }
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(values);
  } catch (err) {
  }
}
```

it returns `,,,,,,,,https,,,,,,,,,hngui` but needed `[[, , , , , , , , https], [, , , , , , , , hngui]]`

Comment: In your script, how about modifing from `return ContentService.createTextOutput(values);` to `return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(values));`? Or, if you want to give the response mimeType, how about `return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(values)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);` or `ContentService.MimeType.TEXT`?

Comment: who/what is calling `getAllProducts` ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getAllProducts() {
  const spreadsheetId = '000000-PA2yI4OmUjTn3xz9o4faP-8-iPOniBYc0kuKc';
  const rangeName = 'Products!A2:I1000';
  try {
    const values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, rangeName).values;
    if (!values) {
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("No Product Found");
    }
    Logger.log(values);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(values));
  } catch (err) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).